macos/bash: read "hangs" when executing script second time as another user with stdout redirected before
Hello! My second file descriptors question.
Context: Still new at this, I certainly don't get file descriptors. Magic. Unpredictable magic at that, that sometimes works. (joke, but you probably get my frustration here). Install script.
Situation: Cross platform-y install script, mac/win/linux. (a) Runs twice - started as su, script runs first part where su is needed and then reruns itself in order to run second part as normal user, where that is needed. (b) Detailed logging redirected to file. Main messages to console. (c) Running this on macos currently. (Windows/mingw does not suffer this issue, but that is a different story)
Goal: After both parts have run, ask user question at end of script, if diagnostic tests should be run. I am using read for this.
Problem: The combination of running a second time and redirecting stdout to a logfile causes read to behave oddly and seemingly hang. I need to kill the console and restart.
I found a "workaround" to continue/not hang atleast, adding a fd redirect "reset", using tty (i e exec &>/dev/tty) before starting the "second run". But most often read fails to read afterwards, the variable does not contain the typed character. I'm stumped.
Observation: read echoes sometimes...
Another thing I noticed, that I think is related here: Sometimes read will echo the typed character, and sometimes not. (Again, the magic) It seems to depend on how many times the redirection, etc has been done... so something obviously toggles it, likely the redirection, not sure what/how. It is just so frustratingly unpredictable. First read echoes and then next does not, etc.
Questions:
Would love to know:

How to solve this problem (given the situation/constraints I have stated)? No hang, and complete the read and get the behavior predictable.
(If it is easy/reasonably manageable to understand) what is going on / causing this issue?

Repro script
This allows the behavior to be seen on the mac: (I have tried to make it concise, hence the compressed if's for instance, not how I do it in production, ofc) [mac-read-hangs.sh]
To trigger the hanging problem, comment the line exec &>/dev/tty # TO REPRO... and enjoy killing your console ;-)
#!/bin/bash
# exec &>/dev/tty # I seem to need this as well... but it seems to work without... 
echo "Starting script...  $(date -Iseconds) $@"

if [[ "$1" == "SECONDRUN" ]]; then
    echo -e -n "2.1 Do you want to continue? Type y to continue. "
    read -rep "=> " CONTINUE_ENTRY; echo "You typed: ${CONTINUE_ENTRY}"
    if [ "$CONTINUE_ENTRY" != "y" ]; then echo "OK, exiting."; exit 0; fi

    exec 3>&1 1>>testlogs.txt 2>&1 
else
    exec 3>&1 1>>testlogs.txt 2>&1 
    echo -e -n "1. Do you want to continue? Type y to continue. " >&3
    read -rep "=> " CONTINUE_ENTRY >&3; echo "You typed: ${CONTINUE_ENTRY}" >&3
    if [ "$CONTINUE_ENTRY" != "y" ]; then echo "OK, exiting." >&3; exit 0; fi

    exec &>/dev/tty # TO REPRO! Comment this and it will hang on 2.2. It will hang on 2.1 if you have run it before... ??
    CURRENT_DIR=$(PWD)
    su - $SUDO_USER -c "$CURRENT_DIR/mac-read-hangs.sh SECONDRUN"
    echo "1. Secondrun completed." >&3
    exit 0
fi

echo -e -n "2.2 Do you want to continue? Type y to continue. " >&3
read -rep "=> " CONTINUE_ENTRY >&3; echo "You typed: ${CONTINUE_ENTRY}" >&3
if [ "$CONTINUE_ENTRY" != "y" ]; then echo "OK, exiting." >&3; exit 0; fi
echo "<Do some more stuff...>(end)"

Example execution
@MAC-P-C02GG2X4ML7H getting-started % sudo ./mac-read-hangs.sh
Starting script...  2024-07-19T13:39:25+02:00 
1. Do you want to continue? Type y to continue. You typed: y
Starting script...  2024-07-19T13:39:26+02:00 SECONDRUN
2.1 Do you want to continue? Type y to continue. => y
You typed: y
2.2 Do you want to continue? Type y to continue. You typed: y
1. Secondrun completed.
@MAC-P-C02GG2X4ML7H getting-started % 

